# Sort dictionary by value but when the value is the same

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this dictionary:

```
a = {'Atlanta': 4, 'Bronx': 4, 'San Diego': 30}
```

I currently know how to sort it by value from greatest to least:

```
s = sorted(a.items(), key = lambda t:t[1], reverse=True)

s = [('San Diego', 30), ('Atlanta', 4), ('Bronx', 4)]
```

What I want to do is when the value of two keys are the same, I want to sort them in reverse alphabetical order. So my desired result would be:

```
s = [('San Diego', 30), ('Bronx', 4), ('Atlanta', 4)]
```

instead of what I have above. Is there a convenient way to do this?

Comment: that's called a tiebreaker in sort lingo

Answer (score 3):

You can sort the tuples with the tuple elements themselves in reverse order:

```
s = sorted(a.items(), key = lambda t: t[::-1], reverse=True)
```

or you can make it more explicit with:

```
s = sorted(a.items(), key = lambda t: (t[1], t[0]), reverse=True)
```

The above works because a tuple is less than another tuple given the first item of the first tuple is less than the other tuple, or the two items are equal and the next item of the first tuple is less than the next item of the second item, and so on. So `(a1, a2) < (b1, b2)` given `a1 < b1 or (a1 == b1 and a2 < b2)`. It thus means that by swapping the two tuple items, we first compare on the value, and then on the key in case this is a tie.

Comment: Very nice, quick too :)

Answer (score 3):

You can sort a secondary condition with a tuple

```
s = dict(sorted(a.items(), key= lambda x: (x[1], x[0]), reverse = True))
# {'San Diego': 30, 'Bronx': 4, 'Atlanta': 4}
```